# Multiple RDP running in parallel and limit resources for each user

Tags: virtualbox, remote-desktop

I'm trying to create multiple users on windows with the possibility of running them in parallel and limiting the resources for each user to take an equal portion (or even determine specific resources for each user -not equally-).

1- Is it doable on windows 10? or windows server is required?
2- Do I need to buy software for this or are the built-in tools in Windows sufficient?
3- If each user needs access to a Linux system installed on a VirtualBox, will it be possible to run in parallel as well or each user should have his own virtual system?

Comment: idk enough to make this an answer, but 1) You need Windows Server. 2) https://www.exitthefastlane.com/2018/02/resource-sharing-in-server2016-rdsh.html 3) I've no idea.

Comment: Thank you, any answer is appreciated anyway.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Microsoft does not condone hacking the RDP protocol to do what this question suggests, so yeah, this is definitely not legal in a commercial or production environment.

Comment: Buying Windows Server licenses and CALs is cheap anyway if you want terminal services for production or commercial usage use a server (and configuration) that has support.